# Add product to wishlist using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, wishlist

How can i add product to wishlist from catalog page using ajax can anyone provide me the code

Comment: Please add code which you did so far.

Comment: refer http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/27/magento-ajax-based-add-product-to-wishlist-and-compare-products/